# How to query Solr to get the documents if it matches 50% of the query string?

Tags: solr, lucene, dismax

I am using Solr 7.6 with the document structure is as follows:

```
{
    "source_ln":"en",
    "source_text":"the sky is blue",
    "target_ln":"hi",
    "target_text":"आसमान नीला है",
},
{
    "source_ln":"en",
    "source_text":"the sky is also called the celestial sphere",
    "target_ln":"hi",
    "target_text":"आकाश को आकाशीय क्षेत्र भी कहा जाता है",
}
```

All the fields are defined with the StandardTokenizerFactory tokenizer.

When I query "source_text":"the sky",

The result set should contain the first document only.

In the second document the field "source_text":"the sky is also called the celestial sphere" contains 8 terms and the query field "source_text":"the sky" contains the 2 terms only, So the at least 50% match criteria is not fulfilled and hence 2nd document would not be in the result set.

Is there any way to get the documents matching at least 50% of the query field terms/tokens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your request handler to use a [(e)dismax](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html) query parser, for example using the [`defType`parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-ThedefTypeParameter) eg. `?q=...&defType=dismax`.

Using a dismax parser, you can then use the [`mm` (Minimum Should Match)](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm_MinimumShouldMatch_Parameter) parameter according to your needs, just by setting `mm=50%`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the features by doing below steps.

- Create separate field in your schema name "source_text_fifty",
  param(indexing=true, storing=false, and don't apply
  StandardTokenizerFactory grammar type or better create separate
  datatype field with solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory ).
- Now, Calculate 50% of your input during Indexing the doc and store
  those calculated data in "source_text_fifty" field.
- Re-index all exiting data with above logic.
- Run query with source_text_fifty:"the sky". Now you got only one 50% match data.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate 50% of the input during indexing the doc"?
Actually I am using Solr to build a language translation. So I am looking for the functionality to get the most relevant partial match results.

Comment: In case of partial match results, this 50% logic not work. This only for exact 50% match from starting of string. According to your example in question.